# How much memory in 32 bit...?

Tags: architecture

3.3 (10 pts) Consider a hypothetical 32-bit microprocessor having 32-bit instructions compose of two fields: the first byte contains the opcode and the remainder the immediate operand or an operand address.
a. What is the maximum directly addressable memory capacity (assume that these
addresses are addresses to specific bytes)?

Answer: 2^24 = 16 MBytes

b. What if the addresses refer to 32-bit words? How much memory can be
addresses now (answer in bytes):

Answer: 2^26 = 64 MBytes

Can someone explain how they got the answer for part b?

Answer (score 0):

32 bit words => 4 bytes per word

so 16*4 = 64

You can also go 2^(24+2) = 2^26 = 64